# BCrypt RSA private key import

Tags: rsa, bcrypt

I want to import a private RSA pem key to BCryptImportKeyPair.
I have no problem to import the public key but I don't know how the following structure and here especially cbPrime1/cbPrime2 for private key blob must be set:

```
pRsaBlob->Magic = BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_MAGIC;
pRsaBlob->BitLength = pKey->rsapubkey.bitlen;
pRsaBlob->cbPublicExp = cbExp;
pRsaBlob->cbModulus = cbModulus;
pRsaBlob->cbPrime1 = 0;
pRsaBlob->cbPrime2 = 0;
```

The problem must be solved with BCrypt API because the code is inside a kernel mode driver.

I fill at the moment this structure with my private blob:

```
struct PUBLIC_KEY_VALUES {
BLOBHEADER blobheader;
RSAPUBKEY rsapubkey;
BYTE modulus[4096];};
```

I know that this also must be changed because the private blob does not match the 
RSAPUBKEY.

The data for the BLOB comes from the function:

```
   CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, privateKeyInfo->PrivateKey.pbData, privateKeyInfo->PrivateKey.cbData,
    CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &keydata, &keyLen);
hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup;
```

I know that keydata is correct because I have no problem with them with the Wincrypt API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done inside the kernel mode driver with

```
    // Import the public key
hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(BCryptImportKeyPair(
    hAlg,
    NULL,
    **BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB**,
    phKey,
    (PUCHAR)pbPrivateKey,
    cbKey,
    0
));
```

1. Include "Ksecdd.lib" in the driver project.
2. Convert the private key from PEM to PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING with the help of CryptDecodeObjectEx. This can only be done in user mode. Lay the result in a struct for the driver project.
3. Import the key with BCryptImportKeyPair and the parameter BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB.(Kernel mode)

A good starting point is
[OPM Example Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/opm-example-code) from Microsoft. This routine is very helpful because here you get the helper routines to lay parts of the structure in memory in the right format (Big Endian).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with which it is not necessary to rebuild the structure.

```
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(BCryptImportKeyPair(
    hAlg,
    NULL,
    **LEGACY_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB**,
    phKey,
    (PUCHAR)pbPublicKey,
    cbKey,
    0
));
```

The BLOB is now exported from openssl und directly imported into *BCryptImportKeyPair*.

Comment: I integrated the routine in a kernel mode driver and BCryptImportKeyPair returns 0xd00000bb(HR_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED )